# using sharepoint site from another Domain

Tags: web-part, domain

I have sharepoint site  named sp working on x.local Domain.
x.local now trust with y.local.
users of x.local can using sharepoint whit sp address.
and y.local users , using sharepoint site with address :
sp.x.local
but webpart and list refer address sp without x.local and not shown.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a bit of info missing from this post, but here are some things you need to check:

1. DNS - can users in y.local resolve sp.x.local?
2. Network path - can you get HTTP or HTTPS traffic from x.local to
   y.local (ports 80, 443)?
3. Authentication - Is your SP configured to allow users from
   y.local?

My first port of call would be to use Fiddler from a machine on y.local and try to browse to x.local.   What happens?

Comment: Having re-read your post I think the issue is DNS.   If the list refers to 'sp' only, your users in y.local can't find it, because they will be attempting to go to 'sp.y.local'.  You need to look at the DNS configuration, as well as research Alternate Access Mappings.

Comment: thanks.in y.local domain users can resolve sp.can connect to sp with their own user name and password.users of y.local must use sp.x.local to connect.becuse the list and webpard use sp for link address ,users of y.local could not use the list or webpart